# DataStructure to store pairs

Tags: matrix, data-structures, covariance

Say I want to store a matrix of relationships between n items. For example:

```
  | A B C
==|======
A | - 2 3
B | - - 7
C | - - -
```

Sort of like a covariance matrix Given n items. But I need it to be dynamic. That is, I can increase the dimension of this by adding a new item, and a whole new set of relationships.

What is the best data structure to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider representing the matrix as a vector of vectors. Adding a new item is then linear in the number of items: add a new vector at the bottom of the "outter vector, fill it in; and add an item to each of the existing "inner" vectors.

This may not be the best data structure in terms of time complexity, but it's very practical (simple to implement and easy to use).